# Python 2.7 Segfault on Debian 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, debian, mod-wsgi

When I run a mod_wsgi app, I get a segfault by Python. I got the debug symbols for Python, but I have no idea how to get the Python sources for Debian 7. When I do `apt-get source python` I do not get the actual python interpreter source files.

To begin with, I was getting a crash within the mod_wsgi code. But after I ran an apt upgrade I starting getting a segfault with the json module. However both segfaults occurred on line 788 of obmalloc.c in PyObject_Malloc. Now if only I could find the proper source code I could figure out what's going on a bit better!

Here is the top few frames of the backtrace:

```
#0  PyObject_Malloc (nbytes=46) at ../Objects/obmalloc.c:788
#1  0x00007fffef3db145 in PyString_FromStringAndSize.part.17 (size=<optimized out>, str=0x0) at ../Objects/stringobject.c:88
#2  PyString_FromStringAndSize (str=str@entry=0x0, size=size@entry=9) at ../Objects/stringobject.c:57
#3  0x00007fffed57b644 in ascii_escape_str.2660 (pystr=pystr@entry='message') at /home/jmm/py/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_json.c:302
#4  0x00007fffed57d25e in py_encode_basestring_ascii (pystr='message', self=0x0) at /home/jmm/py/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_json.c:827
#5  encoder_encode_string.isra.4.part.5 (obj='message') at /home/jmm/py/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_json.c:1962
#6  encoder_encode_string.isra.4 (obj='message') at /home/jmm/py/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_json.c:1977
#7  encoder_listencode_dict (indent_level=<optimized out>, dct={'message': 'Invalid params', 'code': -32602}, rval=
    ['{', '"jsonrpc"', ': ', '"2.0"', ', ', '"id"', ': ', '1', ', ', '"error"', ': ', '{'], s=0x555555d88758) at /home/jmm/py/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_json.c:2170
#8  encoder_listencode_obj.part.10.2731 (s=s@entry=0x555555d88758, rval=rval@entry=['{', '"jsonrpc"', ': ', '"2.0"', ', ', '"id"', ': ', '1', ', ', '"error"', ': ', '{'], obj=obj@entry=
    {'message': 'Invalid params', 'code': -32602}, indent_level=indent_level@entry=0) at /home/jmm/py/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_json.c:2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apt-get source python2.7` for getting the source or substitute the version you care about. The `python` package is a virtual package and thus contains no source.

Comment: Seems pretty stupid of me not to realise this, but you are right. Hopefully I have all the details to try to figure this out now. Thanks.